# strikeThrough Attribute is not compatible with iOS 13

Tags: swift, ios13

I have used this `String` extension to add strikeThrough to the text

here is the extension:

```
extension String{
func strikeThrough()->NSAttributedString{
    let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
    return attributeString
}
```

And here how I use for an `UILabel`:

```
     if isDone {
            self.title?.attributedText = title.strikeThrough()
        } else {
            self.title?.attributedText = nil
            self.title?.text = title
        }
```

It works well in iOS 12, but in iOS 13, `self.title?.attributedText = nil` doesn't remove strikeThrough line. 
In my app, when the strikeThrough is added on a text, it will be removed from the list, but now, it's removed but strikeThrough will be appear on the other texts, which should not be happen. 
And self.title? is also not nil.

Could you suggest me any way to remove `strikeThrough` from the text, the current form with `nil` is not working.

Thank you so much

Comment: Define "not working". [Edit] your question and clearly state exactly what is happening and what should be happening. And please confirm that `self.title` is not `nil` when that code is being run.

Comment: Thank you so much, I edited my first post.

Comment: What is `title`? UILabel? UITextField? UITextView? And what is the `textType` property? Your code is lacking a lot context. You really need to post something that properly replicates the issue.

Comment: It's UILabel, sorry about lack of enough information, I have about 1020 line of code in this controller. TextType is about text color, I remove it from the first post to avoid confusing

Comment: "but now, it's removed but strikeThrough will be appear on the other texts" Sorry, but it's unclear what the problem is. The code you've shown _works fine_ on iOS 13 to add or remove strikethrough on one UILabel. So whatever is going wrong, it is elsewhere.

Comment: Also it isn't clear what `self` is or where this code runs. It surely cannot be a view controller, because a view controller already has a `title` property.

Comment: I know what you mean, since I got the same problem on iOS13. Do you find a way to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using an extension, you can define `strikeThrough` in your controller.

For example:

```
let strokeEffect: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
    NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughColor: UIColor.gray]

self.title?.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: strokeEffect)
```

Then for removing `strikeThrough`, you can simply change its color to clear...

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by in setting value to 0 in the case where I don't want it showing anymore.

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: weightString)

//HACK we have to set strikethrough to 0 for ios 13 or it won't remove the strike even if setting the attributed text to nil

attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: 0, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))

cell.weightLabel.attributedText = attributeString))
```

Comment: On Swift 4 I reset it to `NSUnderlineStyle.styleNone` to remove the style for iOS 13. However styleNone was removed in like Swift 4.2 and setting it to 0 seems to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same problem on iOS13, I using attrbutedText in tableviewCell like this:

```
  if(model.finished){
     NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"finished_titleString..." ];
     [attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                        value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributeString length])];

       cell.leftTitleLabel.attributedText = attributeString;
    }else {
       NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttriStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"notfinished_titleString..."];
       cell.leftTitleLbl.attributedText = mutableAttriStr;
    }
```

It's all OK under iOS13 version.

But now on iOS13, if I checked the Finished List, cell will be shown with StrikethroughStyle, but then I changed to the Not Finished List, cell also shown with StrikethroughStyle.

For that, I try to make two kinds of indentifiers for cell, and it works normally.

```
UITableviewCell *cell = nil;
if(model.finished){
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"finishedCell"];
}else {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"notFinishedCell"];
}
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[ETMTodoFlowCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: model.finished ? @"finishedCell": @"notFinishedCell" ];
}
...
```

Another more elegant way to solve this problem:

```
- (NSMutableAttributedString *)getNoStrikethroughAttribute:(NSString *)str andTextColor:(UIColor *)textColor{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str ];
    [attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                            value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributeString length])];

    if (textColor) {
        [attributeString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                                value:textColor
                                range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributeString length])];
    }

    return attributeString;
}


    if (model.finished) {
            NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttriStr = [Self getStrikethroughAttribute:text andTextColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x999999)];
            cell.leftTitleLbl.attributedText = mutableAttriStr;
        }else {
            NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttriStr = [Self getNoStrikethroughAttribute:text andTextColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x000000)];
            cell.leftTitleLbl.attributedText = mutableAttriStr;
        }
```

Comment: Got exactly the same issue in iOS 13 when trying to remove the strikethrough style from some of the (reused) table view cells. The strikethrough is there even when you assign a new AttributedString with no styles. And you can see from debugPrint there is no strikethrough in the style at all...   Finally have to set the stroke color as clear.  // The above approach of using 2 identifiers is good as well.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to my **String extension** and it's working. Please remember of **dark mode** is you're using:

```
func strikeThrough() -> NSAttributedString {
        let attributeString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)

        attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle,
                                     value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                                     range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))

        attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughColor,
                                     value: UIColor.black,
                                     range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))

        return attributeString
    }

    func noStrikeThrough() -> NSAttributedString {
        let attributeString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)

        attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle,
                                     value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
                                     range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))

        attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughColor,
                                     value: UIColor.clear,
                                     range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))

        return attributeString
    }
```